# How to do between dates in below query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select START_TIME, count(*) 
from 
(select to_char(START_TIME, 'MON-YY') START_TIME from MyTable)
group by START_TIME;
```

I am using above query, which returns the count of all the months data present in DB.
I need to limit it between dates and that date should be entered by user.

Can anyone help me construct and correct above query?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using SQL*Plus you can provide the range dates as substitution variables, but you need to convert whatever is supplied from strings to dates (or timestamps, since that seems to be the column data type based on errors reported in other comments).

If you were getting the dates as part of the SQL*Plus processing you could prompt for the values:

```
accept date_from date format YYYY-MM prompt 'Enter date-from as YYYY-MM: '
accept date_to date format YYYY-MM prompt 'Enter date-to as YYYY-MM: '

select to_char(START_TIME, 'MON-YY') as START_TIME, count(*) 
from MyTable
where START_TIME >= to_timestamp('&date_from', 'YYYY-MM') 
and START_TIME < to_timestamp('&date_to', 'YYYY-MM') + interval '1' month
group by to_char(START_TIME, 'MON-YY');
```

That is, everything on or after  midnight on the first day of the start-month (which is what you get by default with that format mask), and before midnight on the first day of the month *after* the end-month.

If you are passing the date strings in to SQL*Plus from a shell script you can skip the `accept` and use positional substitution variables:

```
select to_char(START_TIME, 'MON-YY') as START_TIME, count(*) 
from MyTable
where START_TIME >= to_timestamp('&1', 'YYYY-MM')
and START_TIME < to_timestamp('&2', 'YYYY-MM') + interval '1' month
group by to_char(START_TIME, 'MON-YY');
```

and call it as

```
sqlplus user/pass@db @script.sql "$date_rom" "$date_to"
```

where those shell variables are in the expected format.

Either way, if you pass in arguments "2017-11" and "2017-12" then the query condition becomes:

```
where START_TIME >= to_timestamp('2017-11', 'YYYY-MM')
and START_TIME < to_timestamp('2017-12', 'YYYY-MM') + interval '1' month
```

and as using `to_timestamp()` or `to_date()` with that format mask gives you midnight on the first day of the specified month that is equivalent to:

```
where START_TIME >= timestamp '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000'
and START_TIME < timestamp '2017-12-01 00:00:00.000' + interval '1' month
```

which is

```
where START_TIME >= timestamp '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000'
and START_TIME < timestamp '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

which covers all possible dates and times in both the months you're interested in.

---

You could use `between`, but the simple form:

```
where START_TIME between to_timestamp('&date_from', 'YYYY-MM') 
  and to_timestamp('&date_to', 'YYYY-MM')
```

becomes

```
where START_TIME between timestamp '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000'
  and timestamp '2017-12-01 00:00:00.000'
```

which misses any data in the end month, except exactly at midnight on the first day. You could try to pick the last day of the month instead:

```
where START_TIME between to_timestamp('&date_from', 'YYYY-MM') 
  and last_day(to_timestamp('&date_to', 'YYYY-MM'))
```

which becomes

```
where START_TIME between timestamp '2017-11-01 00:00:00.000'
  and timestamp '2017-12-31 00:00:00.000'
```

which still misses almost the entire last day. You could go further and adjust the end-range value to 23:59:59 or even better 23:59:59.999999999 but it's messy and prone to error.

It's generally simpler and safer to use the `>=` and `<` range instead of `between` for dates and timestamps, unless - perhaps - you know that all the times are set to midnight, or they are only the first day of the month, or some other controlled condition you can rely on. That isn't the case here.

---

One further side issue. You're querying and grouping by a string, so if you order by that you'll get 'DEC-17' before 'NOV-17', and you can't order by anything else except the count without also adding it to the group-by. If you want to order the results chronologically you can group by [the first day of each month as a date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html), rather than a string, and just format that at the last minute:

```
select to_char(trunc(START_TIME, 'MM'), 'MON-YY') as START_TIME, count(*) 
from MyTable
where START_TIME >= to_timestamp('&1', 'YYYY-MM')
and START_TIME < to_timestamp('&2', 'YYYY-MM') + interval '1' month
group by trunc(START_TIME, 'MM')
order by trunc(START_TIME, 'MM');
```

Perhaps also worth mentioning that the `MON` date format element relies on your NLS settings; there is an optional third argument to the conversion functions that allows you to specify the date language to use, so you can force it to always be displayed in a certain language regardless of the user's session settings. Or you can use `alter session` in your SQL script, or set `NLS_LANG` in your shell script...

Comment: Its working ,,, but it doesn't show current month stats.
For example If I enter between '2017-11' to '2017-12' it returns only Nov-17 stats.

Comment: @AzizZoaib - OK, updated with a safer version. (Should have paid more attention to my own warning...)

Answer (score 0):

Include a WHERE clause, such as

```
select START_TIME, count(*) 
from (select to_char(START_TIME, 'MON-YY') START_TIME 
      from MyTable
      where start_time between &TIME_FROM and &TIME_TO   --> this
     )
group by START_TIME;
```

Syntax might vary, depending on a tool you use to get data.

- &TIME_FROM would work in SQL*Plus
- :TIME_FROM would work in TOAD, Forms, Apex
  etc.

**[EDIT]**

This is an example based on Scott's EMP table.

If you store the following query into a .SQL script (let's call it P.SQL):

```
select to_char(hiredate, 'yyyy-mm') hiredate, count(*)
from emp
where to_char(hiredate, 'yyyy-mm') between '&1' and '&2'
group by to_char(hiredate, 'yyyy-mm')
order by 1;
```

then you'd call it from operating system command prompt (MS Windows in my case) by passing two parameters (note &1 and &2 in the WHERE clause) right after the SQL script name:

```
M:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl @p.sql 1981-05 1981-12

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Pet Pro 29 10:10:40 2017


old   3: where to_char(hiredate, 'yyyy-mm') between '&1' and '&2'
new   3: where to_char(hiredate, 'yyyy-mm') between '1981-05' and '1981-12'

HIREDAT   COUNT(*)
------- ----------
1981-05          1
1981-06          1
1981-09          2
1981-11          1
1981-12          2

SQL>
```

For much more useful information, read what Alex had written in his answer.

Comment: I am executing this query from bash, and '&' and ':' does not work there.. is there any other way possible when you execute it from shell ?

Comment: @littlefoot - surely both substitution references need to be enclosed in single quotes; and really need an explicit `to_date()` around them too? Not sure if all the clients you listed allow dates to be bound directly or just strings - they might need explicit conversion too.

Comment: @AzizZoaib - your question doesn’t mention a shell component. And “doesn’t work” isn’t very helpful. Are you now saying you are capturing the dates in the shell script and want to pass those into the SQL code being run via SQL\*Plus, as positional parameters? Your question should have madet hat clear - but this answers what you actually asked.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yes you are correct, I want to capture dates in shell script and pass them to sql code to run.

Comment: @Alex: it depends; Apex, for example, uses Data Picker item type and you'd reference it as ":TIME_FROM". In (Oracle) Forms, if item type is DATETIME, you'd also reference it as ":TIME_FROM". In SQLPlus, single quotes should be used (along with TO_DATE and appropriate format mask). So - as I said, it depends. We didn't know what Aziz is really doing (i.e. shell script + SQLPlus).

Comment: Well, the question is tagged [tag:sqlplus]... and your example code is using substitution (not bind) variables without quotes, which was my main point.

Comment: @Littlefoot: Your query returns error, I entered "2017-11" and "2017-12" as dates and got following error:

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 24

Comment: @Aziz: I've edited my message so - please, have a look at that example.

Comment: I'd avoid doing transformations on the columns unless you know the OP has a functional index on `to_char(hiredate, 'yyyy-mm')` as this makes the query non-sargable. Realistically the functional index isn't required and the transformations should be done on the binds (also substitution variables) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any sub-query:

```
select to_char(START_TIME, 'MON-YY') as START_TIME, count(*) 
from MyTable
WHERE START_TIME BETWEEN &date_1 AND &date_2
group by to_char(START_TIME, 'MON-YY');
```

Comment: Using above query I got following error:

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 18

Comment: What did you enter? A **DATE** (or **TIMESTAMP**) or a **string**? You must enter a DATE or TIMESTAMP! Otherwise change the query with `TO_DATE('&date_1', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` but then you are bind to certain format.

Comment: @AzizZoaib - it would need to be a date or timestamp *literal*, e.g. `define date_1 = timestamp '2017-11-01 00:00:00'`. If the user-supplied value is a partial representation of a date, like "2017-11", you'll have to handle that with `to_date()` or `to_timestamp()`. If you `set verify on`, look carefully at how the substitution behaves and the 'new' version it shows.